# Find missing instances of a sequence

Tags: statistics, sequence, analytics, stata

How can I find in Stata the missing instances of a sequence?

```
input seq
1
2
4
5
6
7
9
10
end
```

E.g.  3 and 8 are missing in the sequence 1 to 10.
How can they be found?

My attempt

```
list seq if !inrange(seq, 1,10)
```

However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata uses *missing* to mean values present in the data with a missing value code.

Here the problem is to identify values that might have been (should have been?) in the dataset, but are, to use a different word, *absent*.

Here are two approaches to your problem:

```
clear 
input seq
1
2
4
5
6
7
9
10
end

numlist "1/10" 
local expected `r(numlist)'
levelsof seq, local(observed)
local absent : list expected - observed  

di "`absent'"

forval j = 1/10 {
    quietly count if seq == `j'
    if r(N) == 0 local ABSENT `ABSENT' `j'
}

di "`ABSENT'"
```

Comment: Upvoted the answer but would argue against hardcoding the max and min values in case the data changes. So I'd do `sum seq` and then ``numlist "`r(min)'/`r(max)'"`` or ``forval j = `r(min)'/`r(max)' {`` depending on method used

Comment: I don't disagree. I answered the question given. There is some obligation on the OP to adapt a solution if their real problem is different, or to ask a better or different question if a solution doesn't go far enough. There could be an entire paper on how to identify what might be/should be present in a dataset but isn't. It could include integer sequences, categorical variables, cross-combinations of variables, and so on.

Comment: Sure, but I think discussing and improving already good answers and let the community learn from that is one of the best part part of SO. There is a reason the comment and edit feature exists. In my work I have seen many errors as a result of hardcoding based on the current state of the data, so my opinion is that all good SO answers should take that into account regardless whether OP asks for it or not.

Comment: Sure, but feel free to post another answer or edit this one.

Comment: Thank you both for the guidance. However, numlist fails on values greater than 2500 e.g `numlist "1/5000"`  would result in an error. Any workaround?

Comment: Noted, and you've revealed more about your real problem, which is still rather open. For example, if there are thousands of expected values, roughly how many might be absent? I gave two approaches. A third approach would be to `merge` with a dataset containing the complete sequence only and look for the offlap.

Comment: I second Nick's suggestion to `merge` with a completed sequence; it will scale much better than looping and isn't constrained like `numlist`